# Is there a way to use the old menu?

Tags: unreal-gold

I grow tired of seeing the new windows-based menu since Unreal Gold.

Whenever I play in the dark and I open the menu, the out-of-place brightness of it kills my sight.

I remember that Unreal used to have **this menu**:

[image: Old Unreal Menu]

Is it possible to switch to that one in **Unreal Gold**?

Comment: Seems like binding a key to "showmenu" might work, but I don't have a copy of Unreal Gold to check it out, I don't think...

Comment: It does, but it would be great if each time I press ESC appear that old menu. I have to write that in the console each time to put that menu, which is sad.

Comment: Can you not bind ESC to "showmenu"?

Comment: It shows the UT style menu of Unreal Gold as default.